# How can i save sql server except result into the table?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new in `sql server` and try to insert except result into the table for that purpose write this code:

```
insert into [tablediff].[dbo].[TempTable]
    select [Phone] from [dbo].[CRMSubscriber]
    except
    select [Phone] from [dbo].[BillingSubscriber]
```

that code work very good but when i try run this code:

```
use [tablediff]
if (not exists(
    insert into [tablediff].[dbo].[TempTable]
    select [Phone] from [dbo].[CRMSubscriber]
    except
    select [Phone] from [dbo].[BillingSubscriber]
))
begin
    print 'no record'
end 
else
begin
    print 'has record'
end
```

get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>       Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'insert'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>       Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>       Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.

How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: I think that it is [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) what you are trying to re-invent ...

Comment: @Shnugo thanks my friend to pay attention my problem,i want show user what difference source and destination table or more exmplain which record into CRM table and not in billing table

Comment: You can use the `OUTPUT`clause to get a persistant list of changes... or you can use `@@ROWCOUNT` to get the number of affected rows of your last action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `@@rowcount` variable. This tells you how many rows were affected (inserted, updated or deleted) in the last operation.

```
use [tablediff]

insert into [tablediff].[dbo].[TempTable]
select [Phone] from [dbo].[CRMSubscriber]
except
select [Phone] from [dbo].[BillingSubscriber]

if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
begin
    print 'no record'
end 
else
begin
    print 'has record'
end
```